# Xpathing my way forward

Tags: selenium, xpath

I'm using selenium's `webdriver.find_element_by_link_text('searchterm')` to get a webElement. I can then find the `href` value by using `webElement.get_attribute('href')` With the 'href' I'm able to locate the element itself by xpath:

```
.//*[@href=webElement.get_attribute('href')]
```

The problem is that this isn't the link I want to click, the link I want to click has the text 'google reader' and is three colums further down the line:

```
<tr id="AB2Xq4gXoer9sCEEr-rRcZjVz1p021-gdypaX-U" class="ACTIVE">
  <td class="checkbox">
    <td class="alert-type" colspan="2">
      <a href="RETRIEVABLE ATTRIBUTE">FOUND TEXT</a>
    </td>
    <td class="alert-volume">Only the best results</td>
    <td class="alert-frequency">As-it-happens</td>
    <td class="alert-delivery">
      <a href="THE ELEMENT I WANT TO CLICK">Google Reader</a>
      <a href="another link">
    </td>
```

The problem here is that there are a series of "google reader" links, so this term cannot be used

Any chance of navigating down to the element/ link I want via path?

I've been trying by going to parent, and then down to the right child, but I'm just not getting there.

Appreciative of any time and help given!!

Sincerely

Comment: In this example, what is the "searchterm?"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Compare the `a`'s `text()` to the string:

```
 .//a[text()="Google Reader"]
```

To get from the FOUND TEXT to the corresponding `Google Reader`, use `..` (parent) and `following-sibling`:

```
.//a[text()="FOUND TEXT"]/../following-sibling::td/a[text()="Google Reader"]
```

Comment: +1 according the info provided should work. But I expect it will be bit more complicated :)

Comment: @choroba  not that easy unfortunatley, there is a long list of "google reader" links on the page

Answer (score 0):

well, I would try the following:

```
String xPathLink="//a[contains(text(),'Google Reader')]"
    List<WebElement> a=driver.findElements(By.xpath(xPathLink));


      a.get(0).click();
//or         a.get(1).click();
//or         a.get(2).click();
```

it depends upon the order in element list containing 'Google Reader'

Well, firebug will give you a hint about the element you need to click on.
[image]